# Error installing Open3D C++ library on Windows

Tags: c++, open3d

I've been trying to use the Open3D C++ library on windows, but to no avail.
I downloaded the binaries and tried to run example/cpp/Draw.cpp from https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/tree/master/examples/cpp

However, I get linker errors related to `fmt::v6::basic_data` when running the example

In Visual Studio Properties I set:

- C/C++:General -> Additional Include Directories: `C:\cpp\libs\Open3D_install\include`
- C/C++:General -> Additional Include Directories: `C:\cpp\libs\Open3D_install\include\open3d\3rdparty`
- Linker:Input -> Additional Dependencies : `C:\cpp\libs\Open3D_install\lib\Open3D.lib`

And I set added the Open3D.dll to path.

I tried setting `#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY` above my inlcudes, but that resulted in `Access violation reading rocation` in Open3.dll, so I don't know if that's the correct approach.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution.

After adding `FMT_HEADER_ONLY` apparently I only needed to add the resource files located in `Open3D_install\bin` to `$(ProjectDir)/share` as `FilamentEngine.cpp` checks for the resource directory path when visualizing things in Open3D.